# What is the effect of content: "\0020"; property?

Tags: css

```
.container:after {
content: "\0020";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
overflow:hidden;}
```

Contents

Please explain what is the effect of "content: "\0020"; property?

Comment: it's simply a space in unicode.

Comment: Explained here: http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/

Comment: @John Actually, this code snippet doesn’t really display anything so “you can try and see” is not easily done.

Comment: It's a property that inserts a character(s) :before or :after an element. Did you forget about google ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\0020` inserts the Unicode code point U+0020, which is a space. So the code is equivalent to `content: ' ';`.

`content: x` replaces the content (= the displayed text) with the value `x`.

However, in the snippet you’ve posted, this content is made invisible anyway so you won’t actually see anything. The code is a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) implementation to re-float elements on the page.

Comment: Why they decided to take hex unicode and not just html-entities is another story though...

Comment: @Christoph This is CSS, you can’t use HTML entities here. And even in HTML you should in general *not* use HTML entities (except for `<`, `>` and `&` of course) but Unicode characters (but of course this may not always be practical when entering characters which aren’t located on your keyboard …).

Comment: 1) i know 2) i know and of course this can be said nowadays, but there were time when using utf encoding was not the de-facto standard...

Comment: @Christoph Re 1): then why did you post the comment, if you knew that it couldn’t be used here.

Comment: Because this was a matter on Definition.

Answer (score 2):

That adds a space character to clear floats. Google clearfix and you will see similar things.

Reference:
The content property may contain: text strings, URI of external resources (an image for example), and ASCII code special characters. For high quality typesetting it is recommended using ISO 10646 characters and encoding them in their HEX representation.

A single space HEX is 20, so you would use \0020

Comment: “For high quality typesetting it is recommended …” – what. Why?