# Green Check mark not getting displayed properly in css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a green check mark in CSS in the following way: 
[image: ActualImage]

I am using the following CSS in order to get that:

```
div.default.tabs ul.child:first-child li.child.active::after 
  {   
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 10.5px;
  content: "✔";
  font-size:xx-large;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#9CD106;
  font-weight: normal;
  }
```

At this moment, I am getting some list of alphabets(as shown in below image) in place of a green check mark although in the content section, I have put ✔. Just want to know why this is happening and how we can get the same check mark as shown in the top image.

[image: ImageAchieved]

Comment: Try `content: '\2713';`

Comment: Can you please post the html and create a snippet. It would be much easier to resolve your query then.

Comment: Here are a few checkmark options for CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34142291/3597276

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for sending me the link.  I am using \2714\0020 but the check mark which I am getting is not of the same width and shape as it is in the top image. Is there any changes in the code I have to make in order to get that ?

Comment: Hi junkfoodjunkie, I am using  \2714\0020 but still wondering how to get the exact shape as shown in the top image.

Comment: when you use \2714 , that's an actual checkmark character in the font you are using for that element.  If you want it to look differently, use a different font that is closer to what you want.  Or just use an image.

Comment: I think you need to put charset to utf-8 in meta tag like this; <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Hi Victoria, it works by using <meta charset="utf-8">. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For external stylesheets, you should also specify the character encoding in the stylesheet itself, via [@charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@charset). (From my experience, without it especially Chrome has the nasty habit of showing exactly what your screenshot shows randomly ... sometimes it displays the character perfectly, and then after a reload not, and so on ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility: don't use a character at all.  Since you want a checkmark that's very squared off, create it out of the borders of a pseudo-element, rotated as needed.

```css
ul {width:200px; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
li {position:relative; background:#658B00; margin:0; padding:3px; color:white; border-radius:4px;}
li::after {  
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  right:4px;
  top:6px;
  width:14px;
  height:5px; 
  border-left:4px solid #9CD106;
  border-bottom:4px solid #9CD106;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>testing</li>
</ul>
```