# Easy way to customize the bullets for my list element in AnguIarJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on an angularJS webpage. I have a data type for a list.
in HTML, it looks like this:

```
<div class="basic-page__section-list--mylist" ng-if="section.theList">
<ul class="section-list section-list--mylist">
<li ng-repeat="listItem in section.theList">{{ listItem }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

in JS:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.applySettings({
theList: [

"Alaska",
"Arkansas",
"Florida",
"Texas", 
]
},{
```

This does what it's supposed to. It prints out a list where Alaska, Arkansas, Florida, Texas are the elements.

However, I want to customize what the bullet looks like it. Instead of the default (which is a point) I would like to use a checkmark. I would also like to know how to further customize the bullets in the future, if I decide to change the symbol, their color, etc.

I know it's probably a CSS thing, but I am not very familiar with it.

Do I need to make a class called:

```
.basic-page__section-list
{
}
```

and what should I write in it ?

Thank you!

Comment: check this : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use tick / checkmark symbol (✓) instead of bullets in unordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141950/how-to-use-tick-checkmark-symbol-instead-of-bullets-in-unordered-list)

Comment: use ngClass to add the custom css